# iOS APNS - Sending Push Notifications in Multiple Environments (Staging, QA, Production)

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have an iOS app with a set of APNS certificate and will have three environments in which I want to use / test the app: Staging, QA, Production.

Obviously, I want my pushes to be completely isolated in each environment.(ie., pushes to one user on Staging shouldn't effect the same user on Production or QA).  What is the preferred way to achieve this?  Should each environment of my iOS app have it's own bundle identifier and it's own set of push certificates?

Comment: Which service do you user for pushes? Or own solution?

Comment: @ArtemNovichkov we have our own servers which connect to APNS and send the data for the pushes

Comment: you can create three instance of server for different app environments with different databases

Comment: @ArtemNovichkov i think we might be talking about different things.  We have 3 servers with 3 different databases already.  The problem is: if User A is using the Production version of the app, and User B is on the QA version, and User B does an action that would trigger a Push to User A (in QA), User A will also receive it on their Production App because they have the same Device ID across all Environments

Comment: do you use different push certificates for dev and ad hoc?

Comment: @ArtemNovichkov no, all 3 Environments use the same set of Push Certs

Comment: you need to create ad hoc push certificate for Production server

Comment: @ArtemNovichkov and what about for my other Environments?  For example, what if I had 4 Environments?  How do I keep each one isolated from the other?

Comment: I guess you can create two or more dev certificates for your environments

Comment: @Djt Even if deviceid is same but reqeustId/token value while registering for APNS will be different for every device. So should not create any problem.